# What does 'del self.self ' in an __init__ function mean?

Tags: python

I see someone's code this way:

```py
class SomeClass(ParentClass):
    def __init__(
        self,
        attribute_1,
        attribute_2
    ):
        self.__dict__.update(locals())
        del self.self
```

I can understand the first line -- adding new attributes to the `ParentClass`' attribute dictionary. But what is `del self.self`?

I tried to see what `self.self` is.
It is exactly THAT self. Why should one delete the object in its `__init__` function? When I stepped out `__init__`, I found the object still existed with the same address.

```
self
Out[2]: <classname at 0x244ee3f6a90>
self.self
Out[3]: <classname at 0x244ee3f6a90>
self.self.self
Out[4]: <classname at 0x244ee3f6a90>
```

Comment: Because whoever decided to do this: `self.__dict__.update(locals())` is a terribly lazy coder.

Comment: "I can understand the first line -- adding new attributes to the ParentClass' attribute dictionary" That's actually **not** what's happening. It's adding the attributes to the current instance being initialized, the instance of `SomeClass`, instances carry around their *own dict*, the class dict is the classes namespace, i.e. where class-level variables are found. Instance variables belong to the instance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`self` is a local variable, so it appears in `locals()`.

`self.__dict__.update(locals())` adds an attribute to the new object for every local variable, including `self`. Since that attribute is apparently not required, it gets deleted.

Answer (score 10):

The line: `self.__dict__.update(locals())` results in three names being bound as attributes of `self`: `self`, `attribute_1`, `attribute_2`. The `del self.self` simply removes the unwanted self attribute on the object named by the name self.

This is lazy. It would be better to simply have the two lines:

```
self.attribute_1 = attribute_1
self.attribute_2 = attribute_2
```